# How do I filter in URL a serializer when it's nested in another serializer In Django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm creating an API that has nested data like in the picture [image]
Now how to search nested data in URL here's my model

```
class Robot(models.Model):
    robot = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    short_Description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    parameter = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    jenkins_job = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='JenkinsJobName')
    jenkins_token = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='JenkinsToken')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.robot

class assignParameter(models.Model): 
    parameterName = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    assignRobot= models.ForeignKey(Robot, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='param', blank=True, null=True)
```

Here's my serializer.py

```
from .models import Robot,assignParameter
from rest_framework import serializers

class assignParameterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta: 
        model = assignParameter
        fields = ['id', 'parameterName', 'assignRobot']


class RobotSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    param = assignParameterSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    JenkinJobName = jenkinsHistorySerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta: 
        model = Robot
        fields = ['id', 'robot', 'short_Description', 'status', 'parameter', 'jenkins_job',  'jenkins_token', 'param']
```

and here's my view for the api

```
class RobotViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Robot.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RobotSerializer
    filter_backends = [filters.DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ['robot', 'JenkinJobName__jenkinsBuildNumber']
    authentication_classes = [BasicAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
```

in the API URL if I want to search a particular robot then using this URL URL/?robot=robotname I'm able to search that particular robot. But how can I search particular nested data using URL?

using my view I'm getting search filters like this[image]

But that is not performing any Search. how to achieve that search and what is wrong with my code can someone please help me?
**Actually when i search nested serializer only searched value should be present in list other should to be disappear**.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will need to overwrite your list method in your view, [here](https://www.cdrf.co/3.12/rest_framework.viewsets/ModelViewSet.html#list) it is how actually works, you can add whathever you want to filter or maybe you will need to overwrite your queryset depending on the parameters you want.